# Convert MSWord document to XML

Tags: xml, apache-poi, writetofile

I want to convert MSWord document to XML. I want to follow the same steps as I am following currently from the frontend on ms-word docs with my java code also.
1. Open the MsWord docs.
2. Click on the saveas option.
3. select .xml as its save type.
4. save it.

By doin so whole data will be converted into the different nodes and tags.

This I want to follow with my java code. Is there is any API by which I can convert my ms-Word Doc to xml or any other way by which I can convert the ms-word document to xml.

Please help me if anybody having answer of it.

Thanks

Comment: This may be applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15914031/convert-msword-to-xml-html-on-linux

Comment: @GradyGCooper I tried that. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: A better option...have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224871/is-it-possible-to-parse-ms-word-using-apache-poi-and-convert-it-into-xml

Comment: I tried the html way but it takes images away from the word file. Im trying to replace some text in the word document. I tried Apache-POI but it messes up the format @GradyGCooper

Comment: What version of word are you using?

Comment: If you're using .docx format, you may be able to use this kludge: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1860338/with-java-replace-string-in-ms-word-file

Comment: @GradyGCooper  . I was just looking at that also.  It doesn't matter which version it is. I can use either. ZipInputStream way doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224871/is-it-possible-to-parse-ms-word-using-apache-poi-and-convert-it-into-xml/56215557#56215557